# Rendering a canvas object received from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html2canvas

Good day!

I am new to React and html2canvas. I am making an app which will take "screenshots" of my DOM using html2canvas then store it to an array of screenshots which will then be also rendered on the screen.

I am storing each `<canvas>` object received from the html2canvas promise to an array then pass it to my `ScreenshotsContainer` component which passes the array to the `Screenshots` component. The `Screenshots` component will then map the array of `<canvas>` objects to individual `Screenshot` components.

In App.js, I am calling the html2canvas function then pass the array to ScreenshotsContainer component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ScreenshotsContainer from './containers/ScreenshotsContainer/ScreenshotsContainer'
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    canvasArray: []
  }

  getScreenshotHandler = () => {
    console.log("[Canvas Array from state length:]" + this.state.canvasArray.length)
    let canvasArray = this.state.canvasArray;

    html2canvas(document.body).then((canvas) => {
      canvasArray.push(canvas)
    });

    console.log("[Canvas Object value: ]" + canvasArray);
    this.setState({ canvasArray: canvasArray })

  }

  render() {

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.getScreenshotHandler}>Get Screenshot</button>
        <ScreenshotsContainer canvasArray={this.state.canvasArray} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The ScreenshotsContainer component will pass the received array to the Screenshots component:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './ScreenshotsContainer.css'
import Screenshots from '../../components/Screenshots/Screenshots';

class ScreenshotsContainer extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ScreenshotsContainer">
                <Screenshots canvasArray={this.props.canvasArray} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default ScreenshotsContainer;
```

The Screenshots component will map the array and pass each canvas object to the Screenshot component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Screenshot from './Screenshot/Screenshot';

class Screenshots extends Component {
    render() {
        const screenshots = this.props.canvasArray.map(canvas => {
            return (
                <Screenshot
                    key={Math.random}
                    canvasObj={canvas}
                />
            )
        })
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {screenshots}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
export default Screenshots;
```

Here is the Screenshot component

```
import React from 'react';
import './Screenshot.css';

const screenshot = (props) => (
    <div className="Screenshot" >
        <canvas ref={props.canvasObj} style={{
            width: '10%',
            height: '10%'
        }} />
    </div>
);

export default screenshot;
```

What I actually get when pressing the button:

[Actual screenshot of my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMIoQ.png)
I was wondering which part went wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular library works in a specific way (looks like it's doing a lot of "magic" under the hood - you should look at the source code [here](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) more specifically the renderer folder inside src)

Saving the canvas to the state inside of an array (the correct react way of doing things) will be a problem as it saves it as a complex object with many methods etc... and we can not render objects... This lib was not written with React in mind...

The code sample below is a simple implementation in React...

**Here is a live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/9y24vwn1py**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.captureRef = React.createRef();
    this.displayRef = React.createRef();
  }

  getScreenshotHandler = () => {
    html2canvas(this.captureRef.current).then(canvas =>
      this.displayRef.current.appendChild(canvas),
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div ref={this.captureRef}>
          <h2>This enitre div will be captured and added to the screen</h2>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.getScreenshotHandler}>Get Screenshot!</button>
        <section>
          <h5>Your screenshots will be availbale below</h5>
          <div ref={this.displayRef} />
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**EDIT: based on the comment below here is yet another workaround:**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { canvasArray: [] };
    this.captureRef = React.createRef();
  }

  getScreenshotHandler = () => {
    html2canvas(this.captureRef.current).then(canvas =>
      this.setState({
        canvasArray: [canvas.toDataURL(), ...this.state.canvasArray],
      }),
    );
  };

  renderCanvas = () => {
    return this.state.canvasArray.map((canvas, i) => {
      return <img key={i} src={canvas} alt="screenshot" />;
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div ref={this.captureRef}>
          <p>This enitre div will be captured</p>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.getScreenshotHandler}>Get Screenshot!</button>
        <section>
          <h5>Your screenshots will be availbale below:</h5>
          {this.renderCanvas()}
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Link to live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/1r213057vq**

Comment: Hello Sir, you're right. I found a workaround and used the toDataURL, I stored it to a state array, passed it as props, then rendered it as an <img src={this.props.imgIndex}/>. Your example, however, works flawlessly. Thanks